# How do I limit multiple character input on a keypress event in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have a content-editable div and I want to restrict the user input so that multiple characters can not be input on a single keypress?Any idea how I could work it out?

Comment: Can you give an example of how someone could input multiple characters using just one keypress?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I mean to say pressing it for a long time,without a keyup event between the two generated keypress events

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540335/how-to-capture-key-repeats-with-javascript

Comment: @MathewFoscarini thanks for redirecting me....please close it as duplicate if you can